# XML shape android

Tags: android, xml

I have an oval shape  that I made rounded, and i want to add a smaller oval in the center of this one with another color. When I try to do this, I can see the smallest and they always have the same size

Can i overlay two shapes without masking the other? i did this but I can see the smallest shape :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item

        >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size android:width="170dp"
                android:height="170dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#f00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="oval"

            >
            <size android:width="140dp"
                android:height="140dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#f000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size android:width="170dp"
            android:height="170dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#f00"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="15dp"
    android:right="15dp"
    android:top="15dp"
    android:bottom="15dp">

    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <size android:width="140dp"
            android:height="140dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#f000"/>
    </shape>
</item>


</layer-list>
```

It will display as this image[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
    android:left="6dp"
 android:right="6dp"
    android:top="6dp"
 android:bottom="6dp"
```

To the inner item tag and check